# How to add multiple columns to a matrix/dataframe for bigdata?

Tags: r

I had a matrix with 32 rows 15820 columns.I tried to add few more cols using cbind.

```
Added 1st column -
cor <- c(1,2,3,.....32)
dfx <- cbind(cor,dfx1)
dfx # 32 row, 15820 cols

I added one more column -
nor <- c(1,2,3,.....32)
dfx <- cbind(nor,dfx1)
dfx # 32 row, 15820 cols
```

The "cor" column replaced by "nor" when I added 2ndcol to dfx1. I'd like to add 10 more columns to the dfx1, how I do it ?

Suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you do `cbind(nor, cor, dfx1)` ? You assign the output of `cbind(...` to `dfx` each time.

Comment: Do you need to add the columns one by one for any reason? If that's the case, update your question explaining it. Otherwise, just  bind them all in one call (as pointed by @markus).